# Server closes after one client disconnect (JAVA)

Tags: java, server

My server closes after one clients disconnects,and I can write only one more message then it crashes.I wonder why,since I only close the client socket when it types "EXIT SERVER" .This is the exception it throws:

```
      java.io.EOFException
```

This is my code :

```
 import java.net.*;
  import java.io.*;

  public class ServerPeer extends Thread {

Socket _socket;
String username;

public ServerPeer(Socket _socket) {
    this._socket = _socket;
}

public void sendMessage(String _username, String _message) throws IOException {
    ObjectOutputStream _obj = new ObjectOutputStream(
            _socket.getOutputStream());
    _obj.writeObject(new Message(_username, _message));
    _obj.flush();

  }

public synchronized void run() {
    try {
        ObjectInputStream _ois = new ObjectInputStream(_socket.getInputStream());
        Message _message;
        while (_socket.isConnected()) {

            _message = (Message) _ois.readObject();

            String divide = _message.getAll().substring(0, _message.getAll().indexOf(":"));
            username = divide;
            Server.listofusers.add(username);
            for (ServerPeer sp : Server.listofpeers) {
                if (_message.getAll().contains("EXIT SERVER")) {
                    Server.listofpeers.remove(sp);

                    _socket.close();
                }
                if (_message instanceof PrivateMessage) {
                    PrivateMessage privm = (PrivateMessage) _message;

                    for (ServerPeer sp2 : Server.listofpeers) {
                        if (sp2.username.equals(privm.getReceiver())) {
                            sp2.sendMessage(divide, privm.getAll());
                            String priv = privm.getAll().replaceAll("/w", "");
                            System.out.println(priv);
                            break;
                        }
                    }

                } else {
                    sp.sendMessage(divide, _message.getAll());

                    System.out.println(_message.getAll());
                }

            }

            _ois = new ObjectInputStream(_socket.getInputStream());

        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
   }
  }
```

Server Class:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;

 public class Server {

static ServerConfig _svconfig = new ServerConfig();
public static ArrayList<ServerPeer> listofpeers = new ArrayList<ServerPeer>();

public static ArrayList<String> listofusers = new ArrayList<String>();
public static int i = 0;
// final static int _mysocket;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        final int _mysocket = _svconfig.getPORTNumber();
        System.out.println("Wainting for clients.....");
        ServerSocket _serversocket = new ServerSocket(_mysocket, _svconfig.getCLIENTSNumber());
        while (listofpeers.size() <= _svconfig.getCLIENTSNumber()) {
            Socket _clientsocket = _serversocket.accept();
            ServerPeer _serverpeer = new ServerPeer(_clientsocket);
            _serverpeer.start();
            listofpeers.add(_serverpeer);

        }
        _serversocket.close();
    } catch (MissingKeyException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (UnknownKeyException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvalidFormatException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ConnectException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (BindException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SecurityException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SocketException e) {
        System.out.println("You have been disconnected");
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

}

EDIT:

Exception thrown in the console of the client who disconnects:

```
 java.io.EOFException
at java.io.ObjectInputStream$PeekInputStream.readFully(ObjectInputStream.java:2328)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.readShort(ObjectInputStream.java:2797)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(ObjectInputStream.java:802)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.<init>(ObjectInputStream.java:299)
at ClientPeer.serverEcho(ClientPeer.java:35)
at ClientPeer.run(ClientPeer.java:44)
   BUILD STOPPED (total time: 1 minute 26 seconds)
```

Comment: Would like to help, but that is almost unreadable. Would you please format it properly, and perhaps read up on Java Code Conventions: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-150003.pdf

Comment: We might need a bit more code to help with this. You dont provide any of your server code to see why it shuts down.

Comment: @joey.enfield updates done.

Comment: And how about the stack trace that goes with your exception?  I think I know where the exception must be thrown, but better to work with knowns than with assumptions.

Comment: @JohnBollinger edit done.

Comment: What's a `ClientPeer`?  None of the code you posted even refers to such a class.  If the exception is thrown by the client, then why are you focusing on the server?

Comment: @JohnBollinger sorry but I have about 7 classes.Posting them here is quite impossible.I suspect that the errors are in the server class or in the serverpeer class.

Comment: It's unclear how many problems you actually have, and whether they are related.  However, if the symptom you are asking about is an Exception thrown by `ClientPeer`, then `ClientPeer` is the class most relevant to the question.  If answering the question requires us to examine seven separate classes then the question is off topic here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can tell i'd guess your code is incorrect, but it hard to tell without more code.

At first glance it seems that if too many people connect to your server you just shut down the entire server not just those connections.

```
while (listofpeers.size() <= _svconfig.getCLIENTSNumber()) {
   Socket _clientsocket = _serversocket.accept();
   ServerPeer _serverpeer = new ServerPeer(_clientsocket);
   _serverpeer.start();
   listofpeers.add(_serverpeer);
}
_serversocket.close();
```

A better approach would be something like the following. If too many users try to connect, just close the users connection.

```
ServerSocket _serversocket = new ServerSocket(_mysocket, _svconfig.getCLIENTSNumber());
boolean alive = true;
while (alive) {

    try {
        //Keep accepting connection request
        Socket clientRequest = _serversocket.accept();

        //Check if too many user are connected
        if (listofpeers.size() <= _svconfig.getCLIENTSNumber()) {
            ServerPeer _serverpeer = new ServerPeer(_clientsocket);
            _serverpeer.start();
            listofpeers.add(_serverpeer);
        }else{
            //Reject connection if too many connected
            clientRequest.close();
        }
    } catch (Throwable t) {
        t.printStackTrace();
    }
}
//When server dead close it down
_serversocket.close();
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: that helps a lot actually.A weird thing happens: if I connect three users to the server,when I disconnect the first user that connected it all works fine(the other 2 can chat) but if I disconnect the last user that connected to the server,then the server closes.

Comment: Well another issue that you have is that your code is not thread save ArrayList is not thread safe so that could be it, you should probally do all list of peers communications using a synchronized block.

Answer (score 0):

Your code must be exiting after the client thread is terminated, create a thread that has the server accept method that starts the client thread, something like this,

```
/**
  */
  private class ServerListener extends Thread 
  {
    /**
    */
    public void run() 
    {
      try 
      {
         Socket clientSocket = socket.accept();
         System.out.println("client connected => "+clientSocket.getInetAddress().getHostAddress());
         ServerListener th = new ServerListener();
         th.start();

         ClientThread cth = new ClientThread(clientSocket);
         cth.start();
         clients.add(cth);

         return;
      }
      catch (Exception e)
      {
        e.printStackTrace();
        //Main.getInsatance().println(e);
        //Main.getInstance().println("socket disconnected => "+clientSocket.getInetAddress().getHostAddress());
      }
    }
  }
```